# trying to fetch data with invokerestmethod and curl

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke

hello there im trying to convert the following curl command to a powershell solution

```
 curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/radar/ranking/top?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d)&format=json" \
                             -H "Authorization: Bearer VqMBNIOyImZ_W-T4HIYOq93vnuWozOrNSR4NcsNA" \-H "Content-Type: application/json";
```

So im running the following command

```
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/radar/ranking/top?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&date=$('date +%Y-%m-%d')&format=json&Authorization: Bearer VqMBNIOyImZ_W-T4HIYOq93vnuWozOrNSR4NcsNA&Content-Type:application/json"
```

So i need assistance this is my first time doing this because im not getting any response back and i would like to get a response

Comment: you may want to remove the bearer token from your post.    also, you can use httpbin.org to test basics like sending http get requests.  It returns a nice status of your request so you see that it works.  for example `curl -X GET "https://httpbin.org/get?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&date=$( date +%Y-%m-%d)&format=json" -H "Authorization: Bearer sample" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: $header = @{
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
  "Bearer"=" Bearer VqMBNIOyImZ_W-T4HIYOq93vnuWozOrNSR4NcsNA"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
 }  $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/radar/ranking/top?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d')"-Method 'GET'-Headers $header|ConvertTo-Json.                 I changed it to that but still cant get a response

Answer (score 1):

Here is a side by side example using httpbin, which is something you should use in your testing before you give people on SO your credentials to a private API.  Hopefully this shows how you can use powershell for your needs.

running:

```bash
curl -X GET "https://httpbin.org/get?limit=100&name=main_series\
&location=US&date=$( date +%Y-%m-%d)&format=json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer sample" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

returns

```json
{
  "args": {
    "date": "2022-10-19", 
    "format": "json", 
    "limit": "100", 
    "location": "US", 
    "name": "main_series"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Authorization": "Bearer sample", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.85.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=*REDACTED*"
  }, 
  "origin": "*REDACTED*", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&date=2022-10-19&format=json"
}
```

running

```
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer sample")
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://httpbin.org/get?limit=100&name=main_series&location=US&format=json&date=$($time)" -Headers $headers
$request | ConvertTo-Json
```

returns

```
{
    "args":  {
                 "format":  "json",
                 "limit":  "100",
                 "location":  "US",
                 "name":  "main_series",
                 "date":  "2022-10-19"
             },
    "headers":  {
                    "Authorization":  "Bearer sample",
                    "Content-Type":  "application/json",
                    "Host":  "httpbin.org",
                    "User-Agent":  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.19041.1682",
                    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id":  "Root=*REDACTED*"
                },
    "origin":  "*REDACTED*",
    "url":  "https://httpbin.org/get?limit=100\u0026name=main_series\u0026location=US\u0026format=json\u0026time=2022-10-19"
}
```